# MailApp.sendEmail sending email to myself when not set to in google apps script

Tags: email, google-apps-script

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
to: " someemail@gmail.com , ",
subject: "New change for " + variable1+ " at " + variable2,
htmlBody: "Added: " + addedlist_new.toString() + "<br><br>" + 
"Removed: " + removedlist_old.toString() + "<br><br>" +
" https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/someurlhere ",
})
```

When I have an email directed to a user other than myself, I find that I end up having the email that was sent to them, in my inbox. It shows it's sent to the user I entered in the "To" area, but it's in my inbox. Why does it place it in my Inbox instead of Sent Mail?

Comment: Is it in your inbox as To you, or are you seeing your sent items as well?  The email is sent from your account with Sent By set to you.

Comment: It is in my inbox as the "To" field being someone else. It's like the "sent" email is inside Inbox instead of Sent Mail. Why would this be?

Comment: That could be due to one of these reasons: [Why Do Gmail Sent Items Show in the Inbox?](http://classroom.synonym.com/gmail-sent-items-show-inbox-12938.html)  OR you are using a filter with the "never send to spam" option enabled that is (accidentally perhaps) matching message you send, they will show in the Inbox.  or one of the reasons in this [forum message](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/gmail/hdItaHiUAgc/qtZ8KQHqueoJ)

Comment: I do not have any filters that are causing this.

Comment: Maybe remove the comma inside the quotes on the To making it `to: "someemail@gmail.com",`

Comment: @Karl_S Tried it, didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and found that replacing `Mailapp.sendEmail` with `Gmailapp.sendEmail` worked.

Comment: You will have to provide Gmail permissions to the script (if you haven't already). Also take into account that this way of sending it does not register in your Sent folder, and with the MailApp it does (besides popping up in your inbox)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
var toEmail = "someemail@gmail.com";

var subject = "New change for " + variable1+ " at " + variable2;

var messageBody = "Added: " + addedlist_new.toString() + "<br><br>" + "Removed: " + removedlist_old.toString() + "<br><br>" + "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/someurlhere";

MailApp.sendEmail(toEmail , subject , "" , {htmlBody: messageBody});
```