# MailApp.sendEmail emails the user who is not a recipient

Tags: google-apps-script

(Note: I edited the title for clarity)

I've been trying to figure out what's causing this problem but to no avail.

I created a Google script that allows a Requester to submit a Google sheet for approval. Upon submission it emails the Requester that it has been submitted. It also emails the Approver with the option to APPROVE or DISAPPROVE. My problem: this same exact mail for Approver is also received by the Requester.

Here's a snapshot of the code for your review and kind support:

```
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF(time, approverEmail, requesterEmail, financeEmail, approvalNeeded) {

var timestamp = time;
var approverEmail = approverEmail;
var requesterEmail = requesterEmail;
var financeEmail = financeEmail;
var approvalNeeded = approvalNeeded;
Logger.log("Approver: " + approverEmail);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form"); // Enter the name of the sheet here

//*******************************************
//* Enter the name of the TEMP folder ID here
//*******************************************

var TEMPfolderid = "xxxyyyzzz";     // TEMP folder to store the PDF export
var body4Requester = "\n\nAttached is a PDF copy of the Price Maintenance Form that you submitted. \n\nPlease note that you will be automatically notified via email when: \n(a) Your request is approved (or disapproved), and \n(b) When it is approved and already processed in SAP. \n\nAPAC Finance Team";
var body4Finance = "\n\nAttached is a PDF copy of the Price Maintenance Form submitted by " +  requesterEmail + ". It does not require an approval as per current policy.\n\nKindly process.";

var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());

// Specify PDF export parameters
var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
     + '&size=A4' // paper size legal / letter / A4
     + '&portrait=false' // orientation, false for landscape
     + '&fitw=true&source=labnol' // fit to page width, false for actual size
     + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
     + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
     + '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
     + '&gid='; // the sheet's Id

var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {
        headers : {
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token
        },
        muteHttpExceptions: true
    });

var pdfFile = response.getBlob();

//Create the file...
var file = DriveApp.createFile(pdfFile).setName(timestamp + ".pdf");

//Store the file's ID for retrieval later during approval and post-SAP processing
var PDFfileID = file.getId();

//Save the file in TEMP folder 
DriveApp.getFolderById(TEMPfolderid).addFile(file);    

//Now, get the file and email as attachment
var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId());

// Email with Approve/Disapprove link
var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();

var options = '?approval=%APPROVE%&timestamp=%TIMESTAMP%&reply=%EMAIL%&pdffileid=%FILEID%'
     .replace("%TIMESTAMP%",encodeURIComponent(timestamp))
     .replace("%EMAIL%",requesterEmail)    
     .replace("%FILEID%",PDFfileID);  
var approve = url+options.replace("%APPROVE%","Approved"); 
var disapprove = url+options.replace("%APPROVE%","Disapproved");

var html = "<body>"+
            "Attached is the Price Change request<br /><br />"+
            "<a href="+ approve +">Approve</a><br />"+
            "<a href="+ disapprove +">Disapprove</a><br />"+
         "</body>";

if (approvalNeeded == "Yes") {           //send email with Approve and Disapprove option to Approver
    MailApp.sendEmail(approverEmail, "TEST ONLY: Price Maintenance Form for your approval", body4Requester, {  
                htmlBody: html,
                attachments : [blob]
                });

    MailApp.sendEmail(requesterEmail, "TEST ONLY: Your Price Maintenance request has been submitted", body4Requester, {  
                attachments : [blob]
                });

} else {                                 //send straight to Finance
    MailApp.sendEmail(financeEmail, "TEST ONLY: Price Maintenance Form for processing. No approval neeed", body4Finance, {
                cc:requesterEmail,
                attachments : [blob]
                }); 
}}
```

Not sure if it's relevant -- I deployed this as a web app with the setting "Execute the app as User accessing the web app".

Many thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: If you look at the line where it says MailApp.sendEmail(approverEmail it says body4Requester. I'm surprised it even runs... string, string, string, object is not a proper argument set for MailApp

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

Comment: Could it be that you have two triggers instead of one?

Comment: Hi Jescanellas, I don't have any triggers in my program. I've also tried publishing it as a web app to "execute as me" but the result is the same.

Comment: By the way, I found this one post today in this community about the same exact issue. The suggestions given do not work though. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139251/mailapp-sendemail-sending-email-to-myself-when-not-set-to-in-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried replacing MailApp.sendEmail with GmailApp.sendEmail.
It worked.