# MailApp.sendEmail sending email to my inbox even my even not set together to get the email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have an email script that will send out email to all emails that are in the list of a google sheet. But then, when I run the script, it is also sent to my Inbox instead of only to register into my Sent folder. Before this no issue (after being using the same script for a long time, 1+ year), it just happened a few months back.

I've found similar issue from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139251/mailapp-sendemail-sending-email-to-myself-when-not-set-to-in-google-apps-script) but couldn't get the suggestions work, example:

1. To replace Mailapp.sendEmail with Gmailapp.sendEmail
2. Checked if I have any wrong filter in my email

Attached the script as below:

```
function arrayUnique(arr) {
  var tmp = [];
  // filter out duplicates
  return arr.filter(function(item, index){
    var stringItem = item.toString(); // convert row arrays to strings for comparison
    tmp.push(stringItem); // push string items into temporary arrays
    return tmp.indexOf(stringItem) >= index; // only return the first occurrence of the strings
  })}

function sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("pending list")
  var sub = "Error Fix Required"
  var data = sheet.getRange(3,1, sheet.getLastRow(), 5).getDisplayValues().filter(function (row){
    var date = sheet.getRange(1,2).getDisplayValues()
    return row[3] == date
  })
  var filterunique = arrayUnique(data)
  var json = {}
  filterunique.forEach(function (item){
    if(item[2] || item[2].length > 0){
    if(!json[item[2]]){
      json[item[2]] = []
    }
    json[item[2]].push(item[0])
    }
  })
  Object.keys(json).forEach(function(to){
    var email = "{{user}}@shopee.com"
    email = email.replace(/{{user}}/gi,to)
    var sku = "<br><ul><li>" + json[to].join("</li><li>") + "</li></ul>"
    var body = "Hi " + to +", <br><br>The following require your kind attention:" + sku + "Please go to this <a href='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nMKeW//'>link</a> to rectify your submissions by today 4pm.<br><br> Thanks."
    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,
    subject: sub,
    htmlBody: body
  });
  })
}
```

Also attached what I received in my Inbox:
[image]
[image]

Comment: The question you refereed already suggests to change the `MailApp` with `GmailApp`, have you tried it?

Comment: Yup just tried again and it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:
`MailApp.sendEmail({to: email,subject: sub, htmlBody: body});`

to this:
`GmailApp.sendEmail(emai,sub,'',{htmlBody:body});`

Comment: I don't understand what you wish to accomplish with your filter code.

Comment: I've tried before not sure why didnt work but his works, thanks!

Comment: To filter unique, if theres duplicates email~